# Hello, I was wondering if this means i can't have a magnet holding a hook in place on a lure? also, when does this patent expire?

Tags: law

In reference to the patent: [US2831289](https://www.google.com/patents/US2831289)

Comment: "Would this infringe" questions are really difficult for us to answer completely, and your best bet would probably be to speak with a patent professional to whom you can fully disclose your implementation and seek real legal advice. That said, this patent is fifty years old now, so you should be fine, at least just from it.